# How do I get the result set for a stored procedure with Spring Data, MySQL and JPA?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data-rest

I've recently started working on a project in which a database will be connected to a web application. The back end is written with Spring Boot, using Spring Data Rest. I'm using MySQL.

Up until recently, I followed [this tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/) to get to know the framework. However, the project will need stored procedures, so I've started implementing that. The problem is that I haven't figured out (or found anything that could tell me how it's done) how to get the result set in such a way that the REST api can make use of it. The following is an example of the kind of procedures that will be in the project:

There are two tables in the database, **Employee** and **Pet**:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE pet (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    owner_id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    species VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(owner_id) REFERENCES employee(id)
);
```

As you can see, there's a ManyToOne relationship between these two, an employee can own several pets.

We have this stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE find_pet(IN emp_id INT)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM
    employee, pet
    WHERE
    employee.id = emp_id
    AND
    emp_id = pet.owner_id;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

So the result set is a product of the two tables, containing an employee and all their pets.

I've implemented this in Java in the following way:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries(
        @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
                name = "find_pet",
                procedureName = "find_pet",
                resultClasses = {Employee.class, Pet.class},
                parameters = {
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "emp_id", type = Integer.class)
                }
        )
)
public class Employee {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue long id;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="employee")
    private List<Pet> pets = new ArrayList<Pet>();

    private Employee() {}

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name="pet")
public class Pet {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue long pId;
    private String name;
    private String species;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="owner_id")
    private Employee employee;
}

public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Long> {
    @Procedure(name = "find_pet")
    void findPet(@Param("emp_id") Integer emp_id);
}
```

I get no errors when I run my project, and if I go to the port where the information is being sent, I can find my way to a link describing the procedure (that link being `http://localhost:8080/api/employees/search/findPet{?emp_id}`). However, if I try to use the procedure with a correct id (I've tried it in mysql), I get to a 404 error. So for example if I use:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/employees/search/findPet?emp_id=1
```

an empty page shows up.

Since I just started learning about all of this, I don't really know what to do about it. I've been trying to find things but haven't found anything. Is there anybody that can tell me what could be wrong, and how to fix it? Is it even fixable?

Thanks in advance!